# Module functions returning undefined in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to return a value from module function and calling that function from different file, the function executes but return *undefined* 
below is the code:
**this is the module**

```
teacherController={}
teacherController.getClassid = (req)=>{
    Teacher.findOne({token:req.session.user})
    .then((doc)=>{
        var classid = doc.class
        console.log(classid)   // this logs the correct value
        return doc;
    }).catch((err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
    })
}
module.exports = teacherController;
```

**this is where i am calling the module function**

```
student.get('/ranking',(req,res)=>{
   var classid = teacher_con.getClassid(req);
   console.log(classid);  //this logs: undefined



});
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** 
You have to use the `promise and thenable function`.

```
 student.get('/ranking',(req,res)=>{
    teacher_con.getClassid(req).then(res =>{
        console.log(classid);  //you will get the doc
    });
 });
```

*In module*

```
    teacherController.getClassid = (req)=> { //use Promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            Teacher.findOne({token:req.session.user})
            .exec((err, doc)=>{
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }
                else{
                    resolve(doc);
                }

            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: Then you have to use promise , providing you snippet . @VirajPatil

Comment: vs code says "await has no effect on this expression"

Comment: Updated the code . @VirajPatil . It is working fine

Comment: Thank you so much @Pushprajsinh Chudasama ! Worked!!! Just edit `console.log(classid) to console.log(res)` in your answer :D thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Return a promise in `getClassid` function:

```
teacherController = {}
teacherController.getClassid = (req) => {
  return Teacher.findOne({ token: req.session.user })
    .then((doc) => {
      var classid = doc.class
      console.log(classid)   // this logs the correct value
      return doc;
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    })
}
module.exports = teacherController;
```

Then, use `async/await` at your route:

```
student.get('/ranking', async (req, res) => {
    var classid = await teacher_con.getClassid(req);
    console.log(classid);
});
```

Comment: i tried to return the promise but still got undefined ;_; <br> `teacherController.getClassid =  (req)=>{
    Teacher.findOne({token:req.session.user}).lean()
    .then( (doc)=>{
        let promise = new Promise((reslove,reject)=>{
            var classid = doc.class
            reslove(classid);
        })
       
         return promise;
    }).catch((err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
    })
}`